# MariaDB connection problem mysql protocol

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb

Until MariaDB 10.3, JDBC connection was possible even using the mysql jdbc driver.
(I used jdbc:mysql://... )

However, this does not work in 11.0.2, which is currently in use.

Since what version have you stopped using jdbc:mysql://?

Comment: Might it be ```jdbc:mariadb://...```?

Comment: Maybe [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-connectorj/) will have a larger compatibility with MariaDB Server. There have been 5 solid years of development between your server versions, maybe time to upgrade your connector too.

Comment: @danblack so, So what version is it from?

Comment: [10.10.2](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109331), though might be fixed by [MDEV-31608](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31608), so an 11.0.5 upgrade might fix this for you. (might be .NET connector only)

Comment: There is 10.3 version  the server, but nothing like this for MariaDB Java connector. For this connector, are 2.x series , and 3.x series (and long ago, there were 1.x series). in 1.x and 2.x series, the driver accepted `jdbc:mysql://` , in 3.x it does not by default, but there is still a way to achieve it, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#jdbcmysql-scheme-compatibility .  However, MariaDB  JDBC driver is not MySQL JDBC driver (later is known as MySQL Connector/J). So,  can you maybe clearly state what you're using, and what does not work?